# Jmeter : How to check for empty text response

Tags: rest, http, csv, jmeter

I am writing a jmeter framework to validate Rest web services.I have a csv file having the list of URLS , Response code and response messages Eg :
/api/input/checkUploadRequirement   application/x-www-form-urlencoded   200 NOTREQUIRED

likewise I have many URL's.Few of the URL's does not return anything and for them I have empty cell\field in the csv file Eg:
/api/input/savedetail           sessionTrackingID=58ec9684-dfd-4c8f4796-f897    application/x-www-form-urlencoded   200 .

Now If I validate the empty Text response in Jmeter for above URL, I am getting "Assertion failure message: Response was null"

Please help me to validate empty text response from http request

Comment: Implement If Loop > Read the response  using regular expression extractor > place the subsequent requests accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Size Assertion and test for size of response:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion). If `null` response is something you expect, substitute Response Assertion with Beanshell Assertion. Use the following code in "Script" area:

```
if (ResponseData.length != 0) {
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Expected empty response, got: " + new String(ResponseData);
}
```

This code will mark parent sampler as passed if response is empty and fail it if even a single character will be returned.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for advanced information on conditionally setting pass/fail criteria in your JMeter test